# Changing Matplotlib Backend crashes debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, pycharm, backend

It seems like nobody had this problem before: When running the following code lines in DEBUG mode, my python **crashes**. I'm using python 2.7 with PyCharm 2016.3.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("qt4agg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

If I run stepwise, it works. But if I set the breakpoint after this block, *matplotlib.use()* and *import pyplot* seem to get in each other's way. Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Just for information I have same version of Pycharm but Python 3.6 and qt5 and this code works without problem.

Comment: Ok... thank you for your answer. Maybe it is just a qt4 issue. As mentioned, the problem does only occur in debug mode (see my solution below)

Comment: Yeah I just see your answer after posting my comment. I tried in debug mode and it work fine. Good that you figured out how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to figure it out: The solution is to uncheck the "PyQt compatible" option under Python Debugger in the Project Settings of PyCharm. This option seems to cause the mentioned issues when using pyqt and debug mode.